An interesting identity involving skew-Schur functions
Denote $\rho=(-\frac12,-\frac32,-\frac52,\dots)$. I was reading this interesting paper, where in particular, the authors claim that one can get the expression in (2.9)
\begin{align*}
\prod_{k\geq1}(1+z_1q^k)^k 
\prod_{k\geq1}(1-z_1^kz_2^k)^{-1} \prod_{r\geq1}\frac{(1+z_1^{k-1}z_2^kq^r)^r (1+z_1^{k+1}z_2^kq^r)^r}{(1-z_1^kz_2^kq^r)^{2r}} \tag1
\end{align*}
using a list of three skew-Schur identities, given on the same page, by starting from the expression in (2.8)
\begin{align*}
\sum_{\sigma,\eta,\gamma,\tau} z_1^{\vert\sigma\vert}z_2^{\vert\tau\vert} 
s_{\sigma'/\eta}(q^{-\rho}) s_{\sigma/\gamma}(q^{-\rho}) s_{\tau'/\eta}(q^{-\rho}) s_{\tau/\gamma}(q^{-\rho}). \tag2
\end{align*}
Here $\sigma'$ denotes the conjugate partition to $\sigma$.

QUESTION. I was unable to do what the authors proclaim. Am I missing something?

